# jQuery Slideshow won't load

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm using the [royal slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/animated-blocks/). I inserted the following code directly into my sites HTML (NOTE: url's have been omitted)...

```
<!-- jQuery, 1.7+ is required -->
    <script  src="url"></script>
    <!-- main slider JS, get it from build tool http://dimsemenov.com/private -->
    <script src="url"></script>


    <!-- main slider style -->
    <link href="url">
    <!-- selected skin style -->
    <link href="url" rel="stylesheet">


    `<!-- slider css -->
    <style>
            /* you may put here additional slider CSS */
            /* but it'll be better if you move it to separate CSS file that your site uses */
    </style>
```

And put the following in the body to test things out...

```
<div id="content-slider" class="royalSlider contentSlider rsDefault">
<div>slide1</div>
<div>slide2</div>
<div>slide3</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    // Slider initialization, you may put this part of code in JS file
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // slider initialization
        $('#content-slider').royalSlider({
            // example of slider options
            controlNavigation: 'bullets',
            autoPlay: {
                enabled: true
            },
            deeplinking: {
                enabled: true,
                prefix: 'slider-'
            }
        });

    });
// ]]></script>
```

and it appears the slideshow is not loading at all. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I put in the following:

```
<div id="content-slider" class="royalSlider contentSlider rsDefault">
      <div>slide1</div>
      <div>slide2</div>
      <div>slide3</div>
    </div>
<head>

// All your <head> content goes here

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // slider initialization
    $('#content-slider').royalSlider({
        // example of slider options
        controlNavigation: 'bullets',
        autoPlay: {
            enabled: true
        },
        deeplinking: {
            enabled: true,
            prefix: 'slider-'
        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
```

and it updates the code to the following...

```
<div id="content-slider" class="royalSlider contentSlider rsDefault">
<div>slide1</div>
<div>slide2</div>
<div>slide3</div>
</div>
<p>// All yourcontent goes here</p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    // slider initialization
    $('#content-slider').royalSlider({
        // example of slider options
        controlNavigation: 'bullets',
        autoPlay: {
            enabled: true
        },
        deeplinking: {
            enabled: true,
            prefix: 'slider-'
        }
    });

});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: check your console.. if there is any error....

Comment: @bipen i'm getting the following error for the .js files i have... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) + XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting your `<script>` in `<head>` instead of `body`. The `$(document).ready()` already takes care of waiting for the page to load.

Try it like this:

```
<head>

// All your <head> content goes here

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // slider initialization
    $('#content-slider').royalSlider({
        // example of slider options
        controlNavigation: 'bullets',
        autoPlay: {
            enabled: true
        },
        deeplinking: {
            enabled: true,
            prefix: 'slider-'
        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: i put an update on my question as i put in what you suggested and i did not work for me. I noticed that when i hit "update" the code becomes different.